# from list of list create data frame

Tags: python, pandas, list

I have a list of list "list_of_lists" that looks like this:

```
[[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3],[3,4,3,2,1,9], [8,3]]
```

so in this example we have 4 lists, but it could be many more than that.
What I want is to create a data frame with two columns, the first one containing the element of the list and the second column the number of list the element in belong to (first list = 1, second list = 2 and so on)

so it would look like this:

```
element list_n
1       1
2       1
3       1
4       1
1       2
2       2
3       2
3       3
4       3
3       3
.... etc
```

Comment: Which part are you having trouble with. Please provide a [mre]. Welcome to SO. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.

Comment: @wwii  provided the reproducible example, you can find it on the second raw :  [[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3],[3,4,3,2,1,9], [8,3]]. I also provided the output I want to obtain starting from the example, I don't see which part of my question is unclear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a straight-forward after you transform your list of lists

```
import pandas as pd 
spam = [[1,2,3,4], [1,2,3], [3,4,3,2,1,9], [8,3]]
df= pd.DataFrame([[n, idx] for idx, item in enumerate(spam, start=1)
                  for n in item], columns=['element', 'list_n'])
print(df)
```

Answer (score 1):

A comprehension does it for you

```
l = [[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3],[3,4,3,2,1,9], [8,3]]
pd.DataFrame([[e,ln+1] for ln,sl in enumerate(l) for e in sl], columns=["element","list_n"])
```